# Code not reachable in Visual Studio Code with Javascript and Go To Definition (F12) functionality

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I would like to write javascript module and access methods with "Go To Definition" functionality of Visual Studio Code (F12 or ctrl+ left mouse click)

It works well with simples modules but each time I want to extend a module with an variable in argument, Visual Studio code is not able to reach function inside my module.

I have written a small example in order to reproduce it.
Simple copy and paste it in a new file into Visual Studio Code.

For information, I use the version 1.34 of Visual Studio Code.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Example 1:
// - Function fntBad() from libFntBad.fntBad(); is not reachable with ctrl + left mouse click

////////////////////////////////////////
////// Library 1
var libFntBad = (function(moduleExtended) {
    var self = moduleExtended;

    self.fntBad = function() {
        console.log("libFntBad - fntBad");
        return false;
    };

    return self;
})(libFntBad || {});
////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////
////// Library 2
var libFntGood = (function() {
    var self = {};

    self.fntGood = function() {
        console.log("libFntGood - fntGood");
        return true;
    };

    return self;
})();
////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////
////// Program that use libraries
var libCallFnt = (function() {
    var self = {};

    self.callFnt1 = function(s) {
        console.log(s);
        libFntBad.fntBad(); // Not found 
    };

    self.callFnt2 = function(s) {
        console.log(s);
        libFntGood.fntGood();   // Found in Library 2
    };

    return self;
})();

libCallFnt.callFnt1("Fnt1");        // Reachable
libCallFnt.callFnt2("Fnt2");        // Reachable

libFntBad.fntBad();                 // Not reachable
libFntGood.fntGood();               // Reachable



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Example 2:
// - Function extension from ModuleTwo.extension is not reachable with ctrl + left mouse click

var Module = (function () {
    var _privateMethod = function () {
        // private
        console.log("_privateMethod");
    };

    var oneMethod = function () {
        // public
        console.log("oneMethod");
        _privateMethod();
    };

    var anotherMethod = function () {
        // public
        console.log("anotherMethod");
    };

    return {
        oneMethod: oneMethod,
        anotherMethod: anotherMethod
    };
})();

var ModuleTwo = (function (mod) {
    mod.extension = function () {
        // another method!
        console.log("Module.extension");
    };

    return mod;
})(Module || {});

Module.oneMethod();
ModuleTwo.extension();              // Not reachable
```

I expect to reach piece of code that are marked as "Not reachable".

What's wrong with my code?
Is there another way to make it works in Visual Studio Code?

NetBeans editor is able to navigate correctly between methods so I suppose that my piece of code is not to bad.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `debbuger` statement ? Then youn will break into your function anytime you go through it

More informations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/debugger

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the aim is not to debug my code but to navigate into it with Visual Studio Code.